# How does regular view works?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I understands in Snowflake, "table" is just a metadata representation of physical micro-partitions.

How does regular view works? Is it just another metadata representation which points physical micro-partition directly, or is their any routing-like mechanism happening inside the cloud service layer?

Comment: A view is a predefined query, just like it is in every other DBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular view(non-materialized view) is a named query.

[Non-materialized Views](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-introduction.html#non-materialized-views):

> A view is basically a named definition of a query. **A non-materialized view’s results are created by executing the query at the time that the view is referenced in a query.** The results are not stored for future use.

Comment: Thanks, so in contrast to regular view, does materialized view holds "table metadata" which points micro partitions?

Comment: I’m just wondering what the purpose of your question is? Is it just out of interest or would knowing the answer affect how you designed a solution?

Comment: @Njbs , A materialized view actually creates it own table and stores the data, for example is you create  a MV where the defiantion is SELECT * from TABLE_1; then you will basically have a copy of the TABLE_1, 2 times , one by the table and the other by the MV.